# C++ | DLL / EXE - How to call another class method from exported class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, dll, exe

I have a project where I want to use DLL.

I am exporting a factory function into my exe:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
BaseInit* __cdecl CreateInterface( void ) 
{
    return new Initializer;
}
```

This works perfectly. In my Init class I have a method to create another class that I want to use conveniently from my Initializer class:

```
class IAnotherClass {
public:
    virtual void TestFunction();
   ...
class AnotherClass : public IAnotherClass {
public:
    void TestFunction();
  ...
class Initializer : public BaseInit
{
    IAnotherClass* Create(void)
    {
        return new AnotherClass;
    }
    ...
```

This also seems to work. I'm getting a non-NULL pointer. However when trying to call TestFunction from this class (in my exe-program) I'm getting :

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl
>   AnotherClass::TestFunction(void)"
>   (?TestFunction@AnotherClass@@UEAAXXZ)

`void AnotherClass::TestFunction` -body is in separate .cpp -file in my DLL project

Am I doing this wrong and I actually need separate factory functions for every different class instance? Is it even possible to do it this way?

Comment: Are you linking to the import library that was created with the dll?

Comment: `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` normally you need a macro that switches between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on if you are building the dll or using it.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not creating import library, I'm linking explicitly. Or at least trying to. It works for fine for CreateInterface and then Initializer::Create but accessing AnotherClass methods actually throws unresolved external. Do I need to __declspec(dllexport) IAnotherClass / AnotherClass too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `__declspec(dllexport)` to every class and function you want to be available outside of your dll, you don't need to mark methods as long as the containing class is exported.

Note in classes the declspec goes between `class` and the class name:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Exported
{
};
```

You'll also need a macro defined which switches your headers between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on whether you are building your dll or exe, e.g.:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_MYDLL
#define MYDLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MYDLL_EXPORT Exported
{
};
```

Comment: This was closest to a correct answer, I actually had some header-issues too which caused unresolved externals, my DLL was not actually exporting some of the functions because of that. Marked as solved.